# When using factories to test, how to avoid dirty object and callback functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

With FactoryBot, or any implementation of creating objects by simple instantiation and attribute assignment, the object will come into existence "dirty." Furthermore, the object will run the whole lifecycle of persistence callbacks (before/after save/create).

This is different than real-world objects pulled from the database that already represent a particular state, and as such will only be dirty or trigger callbacks if the object indeed becomes dirty or a lifecycle event is purposefully triggered.

On records that use dirty object tracking or callbacks, at best makes it tricky to test edge case scenarios, and at worst makes every save of a factory object perform unnecessary operations.

It's necessary to defend myself ahead of time and note - yes, relying on state changes such as dirty object tracking and lifecycle callbacks can be a code smell, and should be generally avoided. Let's assume my cases are where using these features are worth their hassle.

If my question isn't clear and a code sample is needed, I can make up a contrived example, but I'm hoping someone else has run in to this.

Are there alternate factory libraries that handle this? A way to turn off dirty object tracking and callbacks in the FactoryBot library I haven't found? Using fixtures would also be a solution, but a big shift from the current direction of the project.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that for your use case, using the `build_stubbed` strategy in FactoryBot would produce the result you want. For example:

```
user = FactoryBot.build_stubbed(:user)
user.changed? # => false
user.persisted? # => true
```

This will skip the lifecycle callbacks (including validation-related ones).

Comment: Nice. I don't think it'll solve all my use cases, but a handy tool, thanks!